# How to draw a image over the uiimageview in ios

Tags: iphone, ios6, uiimageview

I have an application in which I need to clear an image by moving a finger over the image  view.
I can do this by using blendmodeClear option. Now for an another option I have to fill those cleared portions of the image view.  Can anyone please guide me how to do.

Thanks.

Comment: do u want to undo the clear u did by blendmodeClear option?

Comment: yes, but that should be in a way as we are drawing over the cleared portion . Like filling of colour by finger.

Comment: Actually by clearing it that portion become white i.e. colour less. So i need to refill that portion. Thank

Answer (score 0):

```
You can maintain stack using NSMutableArray, and keep the images in them after each edit steps. Pop the image last entered if user press an undo option. 

for eg:
[image1] --- > red colored

user edits it and adds green color

[image2] --- > green color mixed image
[image1] --- > red colored

user moves finger and clears a part

[image3] --- > image with part partly cleared
[image2] --- > green color mixed image
[image1] --- > red colored


now when user press undo, u can just pop the last entered image (in step 2)
ie. image 2 . (so we get the stage just before the user cleaerd the part of the image
.

does this help? or ur requirement is different?
```